# Socket.io send data only a client who make request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, timeout

I'm sending data to all clients but I need to send the data only one client (**who make request**) too.

```
app.post(.....){
  myModel.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    ///send to all
    io.sockets.emit("ev", { ...... });

    //// send to one client
    ...... 

 });
}
```

There is a function called `io.sockets.emit` but there is no `io.socket.emit`.

Comment: what about [Socket#emit](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-…]):socket) ?

Comment: But I'm in post method? `io.sockets.emit` working but `io.on('connection', funct` is working only when page loaded.

Comment: Hmm, how are you supposed to know which socket you have to send data to?

Comment: I just wanted to send to who request data. `socket.emit` doing what I want but not working in post method. I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Wait a second. So you want to send the data to whoever made the `app.post` request?

Comment: Yes, It can be say like that. I know it's not possible, socket and http is different, so I'm looking for solution.

Comment: Yeah, the solution is to sent a normal http response :)

Comment: But I want to / have to use socket to response. Thanks for help.

Comment: You could try to store open socket in an object keyed by some unique client id on the server and then pass that id in the app.post to retrieve the socket you need.

Comment: I was trying to do it but it's a little complicated because socked.id is changing even page re-loads. I'm targeting 100 concurrent users so I guess I should use http response as you said, thanks!

Comment: Then don't use socket id. Use something that doesn't change like user id. Make it the first chunk of data that the client sends via the socket. Besides, do websockets persist page reloads? AFAIK they don't so you have to reconnect anyway.

Comment: The fact is I'm new to all these socket and express things so I will try to use easy method for me :)

Comment: I'll try to post a possible solution in a few hours, maybe it will help you or someone else.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that in the post method you have identified the user or session.

So you can create a room per user to later emit on it.

**client.js**

```
var room = "#usernameRoom";

socket.on('connect', function() {
   socket.emit('privateroom', room);
});

socket.on('privatemessage', function(data) {
   console.log('Incoming private message:', data);
});
```

**server.js**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var socket_room;

    socket.on('privateroom', function(room) {
        socket_room = room;
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        if (socket_room) {
            socket.leave(socket_room);
        }
    });
});


app.post(.....){
  myModel.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    ///send to all
    io.sockets.emit("ev", { ...... });

    //// send to one client

    // now, it's easy to send a message to just the clients in a given private room
    privateRoom = "#usernameRoom";
    io.sockets.in(privateRoom ).emit('privatemessage', 'Never reveal your identity!');

 });
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: But there is a problem, room is creating only once. I'm creating it with user unique id.

Comment: How come your "socket.on('disconnect') is inside "on.('connection')" ? How does that work?